# Parse Pipe delimited File with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatable, csv

I have an excel file that has pipe delimited data in column A for for a number rows. The first row has the date then after that is the data. Each row has extra data but I only want the first 3 fields in each row(account name, account number, account domain). The last row has the row count number in each file. Below is a example of file

```
20200310|
Mn1223|01192|windows|extra|extra|extra||
Sd1223|02390|linux|extra|extra|extra||
2
```

I created a spring boot java application and set up my database configurations. I need help creating a service that is able to parse the file and insert the data into a table and compare to the row count to match. I'm following this example for guidance but my file isn't a csv  https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/csv-to-database-java-config-example/

Comment: Can you please show what you have done so far and what problem you are getting into?

Comment: @Jags I haven't done anything past setting up my database configuration. this is fairly new to me so im just trying to read the file right now and am stuck on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the file like this:

```
List<DataToInsert> parseData(String filePath) throws IOException {

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));

        // remove date and amount
        lines.remove(0);
        lines.remove(lines.size() - 1);

        return lines.stream()
                .map(s -> s.split("[|]")).map(val -> new DataToInsert(val[0], val[1], val[2])).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

And with your class like this:

```
class DataToInsert {
    private final String accountName;
    private final String accountNumber;
    private final String accountDomain;

    public DataToInsert(String accountName, String accountNumber, String accountDomain) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.accountDomain = accountDomain;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountDomain() {
        return accountDomain;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my class set up like that already but the real issue im trying to solve is to parse the file not a string I enter. this file will change multiple times but the format will be the same

Comment: You can still parse the file as a String if it isn't gigantic and then parse it more easilly

Comment: I edited my response to deal with a file. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: this is what im looking for thank you. can you show me how the load portion of the code would look like or the insert sql statement in the code would look like

Comment: also do I say `string filepath = "address.txt" 1` or where do I put the address of the file

Comment: I think the insert is out of scope: it depends on what you have, I can't really help you with that.
As filepath you can add the absolute file path: "‪C:\\Users\\foo\\bar\\yourFile.txt"

If the answer is what you were looking for, please upvote/accept it.